# MySQL Query Works on My Laptop, but Not on Server

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I worked on a site locally through my Laptop. I have a table named `blog` and it has the fields `post_id`, `title`, `markdown`, `author`, `added`, and `modified`.

The fields Added and Modified are both DATETIME's.

When a user makes a blog post, PHP runs this query successfully: `INSERT INTO blog (title, author, markdown, added) VALUES ('BLA', 'BLA', 'BLA', NOW())`

I've gone into phpMyAdmin and ran the exact same query with working results.

Now, I exported my exact database into the server today and I noticed that no posts were being stored in the DB, so I tried running it through phpMyAdmin's SQL and it gave me the error `Field 'modified' doesn't have a default value`.

Why would this be happening? In my database, the default for both is `None` so I'm quite confused on what could be causing this.

My Laptop has PHP 5.3.1 and MySQL 5.1.41 (I installed XAMPP.)
The Server has PHP 5.3.5 and MySQL 5.5.8 (Out of desperation I installed the newest versions. The server was originally running MySQL 5.1 and a lower version of PHP.)

This has been killing me, hopefully someone knows what's wrong with this or how to fix it.

Edit: Here are the `SHOW CREATE TABLE blog` results.

Laptop:

```
| blog  | CREATE TABLE `blog` (
  `post_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(160) NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `markdown` longtext NOT NULL,
  `added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Server:

```
| blog  | CREATE TABLE `blog` (
  `post_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(160) NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `markdown` longtext NOT NULL,
  `added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Auto Increments are different because of my tests.

Comment: It almost certainly has to do with the different versions of mysql. Is there any way you can get MYSQL 5.5.8 on your laptop, retest for that, and _then_ import the database on your server?

Comment: Could you provide a description of table 'blog' on both servers (‘desc blog; ‘)

Comment: @sfk: Added in something similar to the `desc blog` (I like the way `desc blog` looks more...) @JMC: I'm totally leaning on that side but I'll be very honest, I've had bad experiences trying to update individual services installed by XAMPP. I'll give it a shot later though and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE blog CHANGE modified modified TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Or, more rarely, you might have a [buggy](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=38173) version of MySQL on your server.

**I might have the syntax imperfect, I referred to the last comment on [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) at the bottom of the manual page.*

Comment: Will this give me a DATETIME in the format `0000-00-00 00:00:00`? EDIT: I take that back, it worked wonderfully! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First: are you sure the data on your laptop exactly the same as the data on the server? Maybe you're not getting this error on your laptop because the default values are set on your laptop table somehow and not the server -- possibly an issue with how you exported the data.

When you say, the default is "None" do you mean NULL or do you mean literally the word "None"?

If both fields are datetime fields, then set the default to NOW() or, if you prefer to not have an actual date and time by default, use a string like "0000-00-00 00:00:00", or the JDBC friendly "0001-01-01 00:00:00".

Compare the structure of each table with the following command in a mysqlclient:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE blog;
```

Comment: They're both set to "None" but I followed your directions on using the string `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. I'll post more information once I'm done vacuuming :/

Comment: There is no "None" default value, there is a NULL. Is "None" what the client program you're using tells you or is that the default value shown when you see the result of "SHOW CREATE TABLE blog"? Also if that field is set to be NOT NULL and you have no default value, then you're going to keep encountering this problem unless your application always inserts a default value for those fields with each new row it creates.

Answer (score 0):

Dump the DDL from both versions using

```
$ mysqldump --no-data dabasename
```

and compare them (and check the man page for *mysqldump(1)* as I'm flying by memory here.)

Make sure you're using the same exact table description and that both versions are using the same engine.

Comment: I forgot to mention it's a Windows Server (or are there man pages for them too?)

Comment: I ran that command but the output was the same as the rest of the commands I've ran (You can see the update in my post to see what came up for both of them.)